# Can aggregate result query in salesforce be forced to return records even when count is zero

Tags: soql, query, aggregateresult

A question that i want to get answered for peace of mind. Can aggregate result query in salesforce be forced to return records even when count is zero?

example aggregate query I have is:

```
SELECT count(id), account__c FROM Account_Relationship__c 
WHERE account__c in :AccountsList 
AND  ( Type__c = 'Consortium' OR Type__c = 'Consortium Member') 
GROUP BY account__c
```

Answer (score 4):

If there's no rows for a given grouping, it won't return an AggregateResult row. There has to be at least a single record to place into a grouping. It's entirely possible an AggregateResult query will return no rows.

As a trivial example, you can write a unit test:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false) class AggregateResultTest {
    @isTest static void test() {
        AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT COUNT(Id), AccountId FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId];
        System.assertEquals(0, results.size());
    }
}
```

Using isolation mode, we're forcing us to query only "test" data. We don't have any test data, so the query returns no rows.

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

Adding to sfdcfox's answer, when I have done this, I do an initial query for all the records, add them to a map, with a value of 0 for each record, and then loop through aggregate query and update the map, and then update based on map...